# How to remove tags containing the web service method on Axis2 response?

Tags: web-services, schema, apache-axis

I created a web service which uses the Axis2 framework. I noticed that the response generated for the web service always includes the web service method name on the tags. For example if the web service method is `/Login`, the response will be something like this:

```
<ns:Login>
    <ns:return>
        00|Login Successful
    </ns:return>
</ns:Login>
```

How do I remove `ns:Login` from the response? I don't want the method name to appear on the tags. Also, is it possible to also remove `ns:return`?

Answer (score 1):

not sure why you don't want those tags (they are specific to soap request/response), but have you considered a JSON XML response. [here](http://www.quirksmode.org/blog/archives/2005/12/the_ajax_respon.html) is a quick article on that (with a sample JSON XML response).

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I'm creating a web service which is based on an existing web service so my web service must provide an exactly the same response with the one already existing. The existing one is written on a different language and does not contain the method tags on its response. I'm writing the new web service using Java and Axis2. If only I could use JSON, I would love to. However, I'm not in the position to decide it.

Comment: you can try using a Filter reading all your SOAP responses, use parse the XML and remove whatever you don't need, this is in theory.. I've never tried it before.

Comment: Thanks! I'll try that. Axis2 has handlers which, I think, can perform the filtering. I'm just not sure if it will allow me to modify the XML response.